# Finding the maximum and minimum elements using 3n / 2 comparisons?

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to design an algorithm that, given a list of n elements, finds the min and max in 3n / 2 comparisons. Any hints on how to do this?

Comment: "too many possible answers"? how many possible answers can you list? I want to know. if you can not, will you please take back your -3 votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a hint, imagine that all the array elements are players in an elimination tournament. Pair off all the players and have the "winners" (bigger numbers) advance to one tournament and the "losers" (smaller numbers) fall into a loser's bracket. You will now have n / 2 winners to consider, and the maximum value must be one of them, and n / 2 losers to consider, and the minimum value must be one of them. In the process of doing this, you made n / 2 comparisons. Can you use n remaining comparisons to find the minimum of one group and the maximum of the other?

Comment: Couldn't you find the min and max in the process of doing that?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yes. I was kind of hoping that the OP would have to do the work to figure out how. :-)

Comment: Upvoted, but you have to be a little careful with the counting depending on whether n is even or odd. I think you get 3n/2 - 2 comparisons when n is even, and (3n - 3)/2 comparisons when n is odd.

Comment: @PaulHankin That's true. I probably should have said "at most" rather than "exactly."

Answer (score 1):

@templatetypedef 's hint is right:

> ```
> public static void findMinimumAndMaximumOf(int[] numbers) {
>     assert numbers.length >= 2;
>     List<Integer> bigList = new ArrayList<>(numbers.length / 2);
>     List<Integer> smallerList = new ArrayList<>(numbers.length / 2);
>     int i = 1;
>     for (; i < numbers.length; i = i + 2) {
>         if (numbers[i] > numbers[i - 1]) {
>             bigList.add(numbers[i]);
>             smallerList.add(numbers[i - 1]);
>         } else {
>             bigList.add(numbers[i - 1]);
>             smallerList.add(numbers[i]);
>         }
>     }
>     if ((numbers.length & 1) == 1) {
>         if (numbers[numbers.length - 1] > numbers[numbers.length - 2]) {
>             bigList.add(numbers[numbers.length - 1]);
>         } else {
>             smallerList.add(numbers[numbers.length - 1]);
>         }
>     }
>     Iterator<Integer> iBig = bigList.iterator();
>     int biggest = iBig.next();
>     while (iBig.hasNext()) {
>         int current = iBig.next();
>         if (current > biggest) {
>             biggest = current;
>         }
>     }
>     Iterator<Integer> iSmall = smallerList.iterator();
>     int smallest = iSmall.next();
>     while (iSmall.hasNext()) {
>         int current = iSmall.next();
>         if (current < smallest) {
>             smallest = current;
>         }
>     }
>     System.out.println(String.format("Max:%d, Min:%d" ,biggest,smallest));
> }
> ```